# How can I convert a string to Date object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker

I have something like

```
var endDate = $('#endDateHistory').val();
```

and it returns as "12.04.2018" (string) . How can I change it into Date object so that I can use it in DatePicker ?

Comment: Split the string with `.`, convert the values to integers and assign the converted values to respective day, month and year of a new date object. That's the simplest one.

Comment: Please share your attempt.

Comment: @31piy—no need to convert to integer, strings are fine,